# BeautifulSoup .link.get("href") only returns None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Playing around with BeautifulSoup working on my webscraper, and for some reason my links variable returns the blocks of code I specify, but as soon as I try to grab the "href" it only spits out "None".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?sort=most_funded")

pageGrab = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

#This comment below is another way I tried
#for link in pageGrab.find_all("div", {"class" : "project-profile-title text-truncate-xs"}):

links = pageGrab.find_all("div", {"class" : "project-profile-title text-truncate-xs"})
for link in links:
    print (link.get("href"))
```

If I also run this script on say, reddit, for example, there are some links which are grabbed but the vast majority result in "None".

This has been my first target on the page for extracting the "href"

```
<a target="" href="/projects/getpebble/pebble-time-awesome-smartwatch-no-compromises?ref=most_funded">Pebble Time - Awesome Smartwatch, No Compromises</a>
```

Comment: You appear to be finding `<div>`s? Those don’t have `href`. Is the link inside the div?

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting the `div` elements, which clearly don't have `href` attributes.

You could simplify your code and use the [`.select()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and target the children `a` elements directly:

```
links = pageGrab.select('.project-profile-title.text-truncate-xs a')
for link in links:
    print (link.get('href'))
```

Of course you could also use your existing code and chain the [`.find()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) after the `div` elements; however, that assumes that the `div` elements will always contain `a` elements, therefore the code above would be safer to use.

```
divs = pageGrab.find_all("div", {"class" : "project-profile-title text-truncate-xs"})
for div in divs:
    print (div.find('a').get("href"))
```

Additionally, if you want to take it a step further, the [`.select()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) accepts a majority of CSS selectors, which means that you could add the `[href]` attribute selector in order to only select children anchor elements that have `href` attributes:

```
links = pageGrab.select('.project-profile-title.text-truncate-xs a[href]')
for link in links:
    print (link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Huge thanks! I picked up Python as my first language 3 days ago, so the structure and system of html still escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

```
links = pageGrab.find_all("div", {"class" : "project-profile-title text-truncate-xs"})
for link in links:
    print (link.a.get("href"))  # div dose not have href, use div.a find next a tag and get href
```

out:

```
/projects/getpebble/pebble-time-awesome-smartwatch-no-compromises?ref=most_funded
/projects/ryangrepper/coolest-cooler-21st-century-cooler-thats-actually?ref=most_funded
/projects/getpebble/pebble-2-time-2-and-core-an-entirely-new-3g-ultra?ref=most_funded
/projects/poots/kingdom-death-monster-15?ref=most_funded
/projects/getpebble/pebble-e-paper-watch-for-iphone-and-android?ref=most_funded
/projects/597538543/the-worlds-best-travel-jacket-with-15-features-bau?ref=most_funded
/projects/elanlee/exploding-kittens?ref=most_funded
/projects/ouya/ouya-a-new-kind-of-video-game-console?ref=most_funded
/projects/peak-design/the-everyday-backpack-tote-and-sling?ref=most_funded
/projects/antsylabs/fidget-cube-a-vinyl-desk-toy?ref=most_funded
```

Comment: Thanks for getting that to work. It helps to have other ways of doing it as well so I know what the language is capable of.